# How to cancel jqGrid cell edit operation

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to be able to cancel Cell Edit operation based on certain condition. I am using `beforeSaveCell` event to achieve this. I can change the value the cell but cannot reject the newly entered value and keep the old value. Please help me...

```
beforeSaveCell: function (rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) {
     if(some_condition)
         return value;
     else
         //cancel the edit operation, how?
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you make some kind of **validation** of the saved value. Probably you should use [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example) together with `custom: true` property in [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules)?